# How can we use a specific command from LaTeX package while exporting to html?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex, html

I can add LaTeX equation in my org file using for instance.

```
\begin{equation}
x^2 + y^2 = z^2
\end{equation}
```

In this case when I export to html everything works fine. However, when I try to use a special command from a specific package for instance slashed command (\usepackage{slashed})

```
\begin{equation}
\slashed{p} + y^2 = z^2
\end{equation}
```

and export to html I can not see the output. How can I use specific commands from Latex packages while exporting to html?

Comment: HTML export uses MathJax. [Here](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html#tex-and-latex-extensions) is some info on extensions supported.